# Handle the select on change event in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm developing a web application in PHP and Javascript and I'm trying to run some code on the change of the value of select here's my code, but it isn't working :

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    $("#projectType").on("change",function() {
      alert( "hello");
    });
  </script>
```

and here's the select code:

```
 <select name="projectType" id="projectType" >
    <?PHP foreach($projectType as $projectTypeID => $projectTypeName)
      {echo '<option value="'.$projectTypeID.'|'.$projectTypeName.'">'.$projectTypeName.'</option>';}?>

   </select>
```

and ideas?

Comment: In all likelyhood your JS is running before the HTML for the select is loaded, try wrapping it in `$(function(){` and `});`

Comment: sorry can you elaborate?

Comment: `$( function(){
      $("#projectType").on("change",function() {
        alert( "hello");
      });
    });`

Comment: should I call this function somewhere?

Comment: Nope, jQuery will call it itself when the HTML has finished loading, it's what the `$(` bit around the function does, it passes the function to jQuery so it can schedule it.

Comment: He's saying that jquery is looking for the element with id `projectType` before that element is actually available in the DOM.  Your function should be delayed until all of the elements in the DOM are available

Comment: The recommendation is the document ready handler @Lisa, which does exactly what it says - it waits until the document (DOM) is ready before the JavaScript contained within the handler is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your change event isn't assigned until the DOM is ready. You probably want this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function(){
    $("#projectType").on("change",function(){
      alert("hello");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error from firebug "$(...).on is not a function"

Comment: @lisa i just tested it in firefox/firebug and i see no error. either you aren't loading the jquery file properly or you have a conflict with another javascript library. i wouldn't be able to tell you without seeing the whole page.

Comment: I solved that by using .change() instead of .on("change") .. I think it's a library issue.